# Why is my layout in Android Studio overlaying?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am trying to figure out why the layout in my emulator is stacked on each other.  Not really sure what I did in the layout to make it look this way, if anyone can help that will be much appreciated.

Here is what it's doing
[image]

Here is my code from Android Studio:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.phil.httppost.User_Profile">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="73dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Submit"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="152dp"
    android:layout_below = "@id/editText2"
    android:layout_margin = "20px"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Bio"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="208dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Upload REsume"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="266dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"/>
```

Comment: better use a linearlayout. Group the elements depending on what you like.

Comment: Hi friend, add full code your layout

Comment: what is the parent

Comment: Thank you I got it to work now

Comment: I didn't realize that my layout was saying Constraint Layout which was stopping my layout from working

Answer (score 1):

Try putting them inside a `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- Your code here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

This will make each item appear under the previous!

Answer (score 0):

`android:id="@+id/editText3"` is not layout relative to any other view.

`android:id="@+id/button2"` this button is not being made aware of other views in the parent layout,basically most of your views defined are not properly informed about the rest existence in the layout,hence the resulting layout anamoly. For example align the submit button below the edit text. For for future design consider a imperative approach in laying out your views. If you dont want that kind of control.Stick with linear layout(vertical in this case).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnButton1"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnButton1"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/btnButton3"
     android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
     android:text="User :"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnButton3" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
     android:text="Submit" />
```

Comment: try removing these attributes tools:layout_editor_absoluteX tools:layout_editor_absoluteY

Comment: basically majority of your views exist, but not properly managed and aligned.

Comment: Thanks I figured out what I needed to do

Comment: consider that layout, please observe each constraint.